# Upload to Amzaon S3 folders staring with a word

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Good afternoon. I want to upload all folders that start with the word "start" to an Amzaon s3 bucket. I am working on a remote server so I need to know what the command for this action is. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3 cp . s3://my-bucket/path --include "start*"
```